# owner and group when creating new folders using php mkdir

Tags: php, mkdir

First off: Im on my Mac using MAMP PRO so I can use it as a testing server for my projects.
And mamp says: "For security reasons, it's recommended to run the servers as 'www/mysql' when your Mac is connected to the Internet." - If I change the user to *me*. So I haven't done that since I'm in fact are connected to the internet.

The permission of the folders is, by default by the system, set to "0755" with *me* as the owner and "staff" as the group.

This makes it quite hard to use `php.mkdir()`. The only way I was able to create a new folder was to set the folder permission to "0777" - which is not a good idea i've heard.

One thought was to just change the owner of the folder to "www" and just keep the permission at "0755". But of course now I wasn't able to work on the files at all...

How do people do this?

**UPDATE**
Here is my code for creating the folders:

```
$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folders=array(
    'dynamics'=>'Hovedmappe for all JavaScript',
    'dynamics'.DS.'libraries'=>'JavaScript-biblioteker (eks. jQuery) plasseres her, og inkluderes i <code><b>load.javascripts.php</b></code>',
    'dynamics'.DS.'plugins'=>'Sepparate <code><b>.js</b></code>-plugins samles her, og kan importeres til <code><b>plugins.combined.js</b></code>',
    'dynamics'.DS.'js'=>'Sepparate <code><b>.js</b><code>-filer plasseres her, og importeres til <code><b>scripts.combined.js</b></code>',
);
foreach($_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folders as $_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder=>$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder_desc){
    if(!file_exists(dir_assets.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder.DS)){
        !mkdir(dir_assets.DS.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder,0755)?$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_status=false:'';
        $_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder_note.='&rarr; <code><b>'.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder.'/</b></code> &emsp; <small><i>'.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder_desc.'</i></small><br>';
    }
}
```

Couple of things here: `DS` is my shorthand for `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, and `dir_assets` holds the directory path to my assets-folder.

These lines of code only executes if I've set a variable to "Yes". ("Does this site use JavaScript?"-kind of thing). And just to make it a little bit easier when I start new projects; I thought it would be a good idea to have php create the needed folders and files.

I just tried to change the owner to *me* using `php.chown()` - like this:

```
!mkdir(dir_assets.DS.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder,0755)?$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_status=false:chown(dir_assets.DS.$_SITE_JAVASCRIPT_folder.DS,*me*);
```

But this gave me a "Operation not permitted". I've set the parent-folder to "0777" in order to let php actually create the folder in the first place. So what am I missing?

Comment: You could run your code to create the folder with 0777 permissions then just run another command on successful creation, and giving it back its 0755 permissions, if that's a feasible option.

Comment: But the folder I'm creating is not the problem. It's the parent(?)-folder. It needs to be set to 777 so the script can create the new folder - or do anything in this directory for that matter. The problem is that the owner - *me* - is not "www" - I think...

Comment: Set your webroot to `~/Sites` in your apache config file

Comment: Couldn't find anything named "webroot". Did find "ServerRoot", and it is set to "/Applications/MAMP/Library" - so I didn't change that. Why should I set "webroot" to `~/Sites` - if I had found it? Why "Sites"?